# Distortion coefficients calculation from single image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am trying to correct the distortion of a fixed camera that will be looking at a fixed plane for metrology purposes. I would like to be able to calculate the distortion coefficients from a single image of a calibration pattern, located in that plane. Therefore the extrinsic parameters will be known.

I tried the following experiment. I created this pattern:
[pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvGeD.png)

Then I defined some random distortion coefficients (only used k1 and k2 for simplicity):
`dist = np.array([[0.8, -0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])`

I also randomly defined the camera matrix (intrinsic parameters):
`mtx = np.array([np.array([10000.0, 0.0, 500.0]), np.array([0.0, 10000.0, 300.0]), np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])])`

I applied

```
mapx, mapy = cv2.initInverseRectificationMap(mtx, dist, None, mtx, (w,h), 5)
dst = cv2.remap(distImg, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

And got the following image:
[distorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwAAD.png)

My first question: is this the distorted image? If initInverseRectificationMap is the inverse of initUndistortRectifyMap, then I should be distorting the image this way, right?

My second question: how can I calculate the distortion coefficients (and intrinsic parameters) given this distorted image? Is it possible?
I calculated my image point positions and then tried to use OpenCV calibrateCamera but realized that the set of equations require at least 3 images to be solved, 2 with the skewness constraint. I tried constraining the equations using cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3 + cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT + cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS and inputting the camera matrix, but the calculated distortion coefficients were very far from the ones I used to distort the image.

The third and bigger question is: can a camera be calibrated from a single image if the extrinsic parameters are fixed and known?
Appendix D in Z. Zhang's *Flexible New Technique for Camera Calibration* talks about Camera Calibration Under Known Pure Translation, but requires two planes for full calibration. (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr98-71.pdf)